# How to go about creating a windows application

Tags: c++, windows, forms, user-interface, mfc

I've been looking at a lot of different options for creating a GUI windows application. Win32, Windows forms, MFC to name a few. I know my C++ well, I just need some advice on where I should start learning some GUI for windows. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Qt has helpful [tutorials](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/tutorials.html). Easy to learn. Open source. Many resources on the web!

Comment: If you learn Qt, you will be able to compile your app on Linux, Mac and other Unix-like systems

Comment: Is Qt widely used in the programming industry?

Comment: Yes it is: examples can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Software_that_uses_Qt).

Comment: The Qt IDE only has an evaluation version of the program available for free. I have Visual Studios already, could you recommend an alternative solution other than using the IDE they have?

Comment: Due to Qt licensing, I believe you may run into issues when you want to sell your app.  If that is your intention, you should look into it.  Either way, Qt is great.  If you are dealing with Windows then regardless of what GUI toolkit you use, I believe it's also important to also understand the Win32 API.  Personally, I often write GUI in plain old Win32 (wrapped up with a few C++ classes) with no other dependencies.

Comment: Qt's IDE would probably be [Qt Creator](http://qt.digia.com/product/developer-tools/) which is free. There is a Visual Studio Add in as well. I am not an expert on licensing. However I do believe the new licencing makes it possible to use Qt in commercial settings.

Comment: Again, the Qt Creator download link is here http://qt.digia.com/Try-Qt-Now/ which only gives you a 30 day free trial

Comment: That puzzles me. I downloaded the [SDK](http://qt-project.org/downloads) this week and the included Qt Creator doesn't mention the trial. Maybe it depends on the license?

When you are already familiar to Visual Studio, consider the Qt Add on and use Qt Designer for your UI design (including drag&drop etc.)

Answer (score 1):

MFC is quite a dated technology now;  The kinds of books/tutorials available for it are similarly aging.    QT is becoming far more widely used and is likely a much better starting point from a learning perspective.

There are of course plenty of other alternatives beyond C++; C# and .NET are good choices if you are specifically interested in development on Windows.   C++ programmers tend to find their feet in C# quite quickly, although any new language/environment does of course have an extra learning curve

Answer (score 0):

I would look into [Qt](http://qt.digia.com/product/), [OpenGL](http://www.opengl.org/) and [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) (Simple Directmedia Layer).

Qt provides an easy way to build GUIs, I would (loosely) compare it to Java's Swing.

OpenGL and SDL are more about plain graphics, both being used in various games and applications.

Comment: Also, OpenGL frames can be easily embedded in Qt applications.

Comment: Qt only has a 30 day trial for it's IDE, it there another way I can use it without this?

Comment: @JessMcintosh: that's the commercial version, just get the LGPL version from [here](http://qt-project.org/downloads#qt-creator).

Answer (score 0):

I use MFC commercially and I'd have to say for strictly GUI/Windows apps, you might want to look at C# (either Winforms and/or WPF). MFC is getting pretty dated. You can get a lot more done in the same amount of time with C#. Sure it might run a tiny bit slower, but for UI apps, I think programmer time is much more important metric than execution time.

If you want to use C++ for UI, maybe have a look at Qt. It is continually updated/enhanced and is not limited to a single platform like MFC is.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It is as helpful to develop a windows based applications! their are many open sources and Ides to develop windows applications.

One of them are Visual Studios, it is an IDE ie..(*Integrated Development Environment*) *developed by Microsoft* for both windows and web based applications development.As it has an advantage that an individual should be proficient in any programming language that he/she knows about.This IDE is integrated with the .net framework which have the capability to manage the code and compile with the help of *Microsoft Intermediate Language* (*MSIL*)and *CLR common language at Run-time*.The type checking is handled by *Common type Specification* for all Programming languages.*JIT compiler is a compiler to execute to semi finished code and turns to code in to bytes*.The main languages are handled by these IDE are C++,VC++,C#,Visual Basic,F#,J#..etc